# Chrome ignores magnet links

Tags: google-chrome, bittorrent

Chrome used to ask permission what to do when a magnet link is clicked. Two days ago it started ignoring it. I haven't installed or did anything unusual with the pc.

I tried reinstalling chrome and my bittorrent client but nothing changed.

I followed [this guide](http://www.roflcopteralert.com/getting-magnet-links-to-work-with-utorrent-when-using-chrome-fixed/) and inserted this line into `Local State` folder

```
  "magnet": false
```

This is a solution, but now chrome doesn't ask for permission, it directly opens the magnet link in the bittorrent client. When i remove the line, it ignores again.

I thought default behaviour was to ask for permission as it used to do two days ago.

I tried IE it successfully asks for permission, and works fine, even windows explorer opens up the bittorrent client.

How could this be fixed?

Comment: Not sure but I would check in `Chrome settings > Advanced Settings > Content Settings > Manage Handlers` to see if magnet: protocol has any defaults set.

Comment: So you want Chrome to open magent link with specified bittorrent AND confirm this with a dialog everytime? I believe the default settings is to just confirm once upon initial setup.

Comment: It fixed itself over time somehow, now it prompts fine.